# 2D Euclidean vector rotations

Tags: c++, math, vector, rotation, trigonometry

I have a euclidean vector `a` sitting at the coordinates `(0, 1)`.
I want to rotate `a` by 90 degrees (clockwise) around the origin: `(0, 0)`.

If I have a proper understanding of how this should work, the resultant (x, y) coordinates after the rotation should be `(1, 0)`.
If I were to rotate it by 45 degrees (still clockwise) instead, I would have expected the resultant coordinates to be `(0.707, 0.707)`.

```
theta = deg2rad(angle);

cs = cos(theta);
sn = sin(theta);

x = x * cs - y * sn;
y = x * sn + y * cs;
```

Using the above code, with an `angle` value of 90.0 degrees, the resultant coordinates are: `(-1, 1)`.
And I am so damn confused.
The examples seen in the following links represent the same formula shown above surely?

What have I done wrong?
Or have I misunderstood how a vector is to be rotated?

Comment: What are the types of all the variables?

Comment: doubles, but the answer was simple enough, thanks to Caspar.

Comment: Also - isn't this counter-clockwise?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

you should remove the vars from the function:

```
x = x * cs - y * sn; // now x is something different than original vector x
y = x * sn + y * cs;
```

create new coordinates becomes, to avoid calculation of x before it reaches the second line:

```
px = x * cs - y * sn; 
py = x * sn + y * cs;
```

Comment: Oh god, I needed fresh eyes... again something so obvious... Thanks mate (works a beaut, 2 hours later... haha)

Comment: when you execute x = x * cs - y * sn;, it gives a different value to x in  y = x * sn + y * cs, so the x will "derail"

Comment: @Daniel: The x in the second statement had had its value changed by the time you used it to calculate the value for y.  So, essentially, you calculated the x coordinate for rotating (0,1) (which is -1).  Then you stored this in the x coordinate giving (-1,1) and then you calculated the y coordinate for rotating (-1,1) (which should actually be -1, so I'm not sure how you got (-1,1) rather than (-1,-1) ).  The correct answer, by the way, isn't (1,0), it's (-1,0) since rotation by positive angles is counterclockwise when view from above.

Comment: This YouTube [series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjBOesZCoqc&t=8s) will give you a deep an intuitive understanding for rotation/change of basis!

Answer (score 113):

Rotating a vector 90 degrees is particularily simple.

`(x, y)` rotated 90 degrees around `(0, 0)` is `(-y, x)`.

If you want to rotate clockwise, you simply do it the other way around, getting `(y, -x)`.

Comment: +1. To anyone rotating a 2D vector for a computer screen: this answer assumes the y axis is pointing up as in math. If it is points down as on computer screens, then clockwise and counterclockwise are reversed. `(-y, x)` is clockwise and `(y, -x)` is counterclockwise.

Answer (score 25):

Rotate by 90 degress around 0,0:

```
x' = -y
y' = x
```

Rotate by 90 degress around px,py:

```
x' = -(y - py) + px
y' = (x - px) + py
```

Answer (score 7):

Sounds easier to do with the standard classes:

```
std::complex<double> vecA(0,1);
std::complex<double> i(0,1); // 90 degrees
std::complex<double> r45(sqrt(2.0),sqrt(2.0));
vecA *= i;
vecA *= r45;
```

Vector rotation is a subset of complex multiplication. To rotate over an angle `alpha`, you multiply by `std::complex<double> { cos(alpha), sin(alpha) }`

Comment: note that this method does not need to compute sines or cosines

Comment: TBH that's because `r45` is precalculated.

Answer (score 5):

You're calculating the y-part of your new coordinate based on the 'new' x-part of the new coordinate.  Basically this means your calculating the new output in terms of the new output...

Try to rewrite in terms of input and output:

```
vector2<double> multiply( vector2<double> input, double cs, double sn ) {
  vector2<double> result;
  result.x = input.x * cs - input.y * sn;
  result.y = input.x * sn + input.y * cs;
  return result;
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
vector2<double> input(0,1);
vector2<double> transformed = multiply( input, cs, sn );
```

Note how choosing proper names for your variables can avoid this problem alltogether!